# How to specify image width and/or height attributes for images uploaded using Wordpress uploader

Tags: images

When I check my website speed using GTMatrix for many images uploaded using WordPress uploader that image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes.

Wordpress by default provides width & height of images. then how and where can I specify the dimensions again.

Comment: `Settings->Media` or http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: No, my question even though WordPress ads width and height attributes automatically to images, when I check my site on GTMatrix it says some images are missing image width and height atributes